# Java Swing: FlowLayout JPanels are sitting next to each other?

Tags: java, swing, flowlayout

I have three JPanels painted onto a JFrame. These are currently all set to use the default FlowLayout. I would like for these to be one above the other in a single column.

However, I am finding that these are floating next to each other on the same line, so long as the components within them.

Is the natural width of a FlowLayout JPanel the sum of its contents? If so, is there any way to force the width of the region to be the width of the JFrame?

Interestingly, I am finding that, if the "top" and "bottom" panels have content which spans the entire width of the JFrame, and the "middle" panel is left empty, that the "middle" panel creates a space between the two, much like the old "
 of html.

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 4):

As Jim stated, BoxLayout is the correct choice if you need to linearly align components.

Here is an example:

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author nicholasdunn
 */
public class BoxLayoutExample extends JPanel {

    public BoxLayoutExample() {
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();

        topPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        middlePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        bottomPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Top"));
        middlePanel.add(new JLabel("Middle"));
        bottomPanel.add(new JLabel("Bottom"));

        BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
        setLayout(boxLayout);
        add(topPanel);
        add(middlePanel);
        add(bottomPanel);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new BoxLayoutExample();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

You would do well to really read through the [introduction to layout managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) to understand the base set of LayoutManagers.  When it comes time to do complex layouts, please use [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) instead of trying to learn the GridBagLayout - you will thank me.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to create a vertical layout you may want to look into using BoxLayout for the enclosing container. This can be set to layout components along the y axis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GridLayout` to create `YxZ` grid in a component. To construct layout more precisely you can use `GridBagLayout` which provides the full control of positioning and sizing for nested components.

Answer (score 0):

I am always go with [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/). Since, I can make Free Design with out having any trouble of placing the components on the JPanel or JFrame :) You may consider it.